# How to get the zoom level of browser

Tags: javascript, html, css

How to get the zoom level of browser???
I have tried many pattrens

```
console.log("document:" + $(document).width()); // same
console.log("whole width:" + $(window).width()); //same
console.log("innerWidth:" + $(window).innerWidth()); //same
console.log("outerWidth:" + $(window).outerWidth());  //same
console.log("devicePixelRatio:" + window.devicePixelRatio);
```

`devicePixelRatio` looks work but in my chrome browser, it default 2.

I am not sure why this is 2....

Comment: [`devicePixelRatio`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/devicePixelRatio) is the ratio between a physical pixel and a css pixel. That you're seeing a value of 2 just means you're viewing on a high dpi display, like a retina display.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1713771/how-to-detect-page-zoom-level-in-all-modern-browsers

Comment: mmm this is quite complex than I thought.... thank you very much!

Comment: This might be helpful: https://www.sitelint.com/blog/detect-browser-zoom-level/